# Errors in using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, linq, parallel.foreach

Originally,I am using foreach to do my task.
However, I would like to improve the efficiency of the task.
So, I want to use Parallel.ForEach to do my task.

However, error "Object reference not set to an instance occurred." happened.

Here's my code:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
        {
             System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(item.a, amount =>
                    {
                         WriteToCsv(file, amount.columna, count);
                          count++;
                     });

         });
```

If I used foreach(var item in items) and foreach (amount in item.a), the code works fine.

Did I miss something for the Parallel.ForEach method?

Comment: What's the stacktrace you get? I believe the problem is inside WriteToCsv. Are you sure you can write into the same file using a multithreaded approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why would you want to do this in parallel? You are appending values to a file, and that is a serial (i.e., non-parallel) process.

If you just use a regular `foreach`, you'll be fine.

Comment: Because there are many data in the database and I would like to speed up the process. If Parallel.ForEach cannot be used, is there a method to increase the effeciency?

Comment: If you have to write to a CSV file, you cannot parallelize. CSV files are sequential. So, the only way to make this any faster is to reduce the time spent *per record*. If all you do is just write the data to file, you probably cannot speed it up.

Comment: I used LINQ to select records from the database and write them into a CSV file. So, there is no way for me to speed up the program, right?

Comment: You don't post your code so it is hard to say. But almost nothing is as straightforward as reading data with LINQ (especially when you add a .ToList() in the end) and then writing that data to a text file... Hence, what would you do to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't nest multiple Parallel Foreach loops, the inner loop(s) is basically stealing resources from the outer parallel loop which is doing a much better job at improving performance..

Only 1 thread can write to a file at once too, so presumably whichever functions your using inside `WriteToCsv()` are martialing everything back into a single thread before data is written anyway.

One way to speed this up would be to construct the text to be appended into the CSV file in a Parallel loop, then using a single write operation to add it in there:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("");
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
     foreach( var amount in item.a )
     {
         sb.append( GetCsvText(file, amount.columna, count) );
         count++;
     };
});

WriteToCsv( sb.ToString() );
```

Obviously you can't control the order text will be put into the CSV file because it's just a race between threads in this code, I assume this is ok though as the same is true of your sample code.

N.B: using StringBuilder is important for memory performance when constructing strings in loops

HTH

Comment: StringBuilder.Append isn't thread-safe as it's not a static method...this is at least according to msdn

`Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

[msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

Comment: @CoffeeMuncher: You're quite right! the principle still holds, but that code is horrible.. who wrote it?

Comment: It's possible to synch the Stringbuilder by creating it in the `LocalInit` function and concatenating it with a local string in the `LocalFinally` parameter of the `Parallel.Foreach` method. Though this isn't shown above